# how to get values from a dictionary for a list of words?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

(Sorry if I write the post wrong or made some serious mistakes in the code, it is my first week in this)

I have a dictionary, obtained with this code:

```
import json
sentimientos=open("Sentimientos.txt")
valores={}
for linea in sentimientos:
    termino, valor=linea.split("\t")
    valores[termino]=(int(valor)):
print(valores.items())
```

That looks like this:

> dict_items([('abandon', -2), ('abandoned', -2), ('abandons', -2), ('abducted', -2)...

But with a ton of words

Then I have list of words (obtained from tweets with the method .split(" ")),
and I need to check, for each word of the second list, if that words exists on the dictionary, and if so, put his value in the dict.

The code with which I have obtained the words from the list is:

```
tw = open("salida_tweets.txt")
tweets = []
for linea in tw:
    clean_tweet = json.loads(linea)
    tweets.append(clean_tweet["text"])
    words = [tweet.split(" ") for tweet in tweets]
print(words)
```

And I have something like:

> [['@Brenamae_', 'I', 'WHALE', 'SLAP', 'YOUR', 'FIN', 'AND', 'TELL', 'YOU', 'ONE', 'LAST', 'TIME:'...

But, as before, with a lot of words

As I said, I need to make a list that, for each tweet, print the value of each tweet word that is in the dictionary (the sum of the words if the tweet has more than 1 word).

I'm having serious problems tryng to do that.

¡Thanks everyone!

PD: What I've tried is:

```
import json
sentimientos=open("Sentimientos.txt")
valores={}
for linea in sentimientos:
    termino, valor=linea.split("\t")
    valores[termino]=(int(valor)):
tw = open("salida_tweets.txt")
tweets = []
for linea in tw:
    clean_tweet = json.loads(linea)
    tweets.append(clean_tweet["text"])
    words = [tweet.split(" ") for tweet in tweets]
    if words in valores:
    valorestweet.append(sum(valores.get(words) for valor in valores)
```

And what I get is

```
<ipython-input-68-30a0230d33a7> in <module>()
    19         tweets.append(clean_tweet["text"])
    20         words = [tweet.split(" ") for tweet in tweets] 
    ---> 21         if words in valores:
    22             valorestweet.append(sum(valores.get(words) for valor in valores))
    23 print(valorestweet)
```

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

lines 22 and 23 are remarked in red

Comment: Can you show what you've tried and describe exactly how it's not working?

Comment: I saw you did some editions, sorry for the mistakes! 
I'm going to add that to the post

Comment: A full traceback would be helpful, so we can see what line is throwing the error.

Comment: For starters, that error is happening because you're trying to use a mutable type, `list`, as a dictionary key. Try casting `words` as a tuple with `words = tuple(words)` before doing the check. I suspect you will still have problems after that, but I am not very clear on what you're trying to do, so that's as much as I can help without more information.

Comment: How about this: 

`for word in words: if word in valores:`

etc.

Comment: @colopop that code doesn't give any error, but when added to the list, it made an ampty list. The problem is solved below, thanks you very much anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am really not sure I got it right, but let's say you have this input:

```
tweet0 = "Hello, I am groot"
tweet1 = "My name is red"
tweets = [tweet0, tweet1]
```

With this dictionnary:

```
dict = {'Hello': 1, 'I': -2, 'Yellow': -2, 'blue': -5, 'red': 4}
```

then the expected output would be a list like this one:

> [sum of the words value for tweet 1, sum of the world values for tweet 2]

If that is really what you want, then this code does the trick:

```
dict = {'Hello': 1, 'I': -2, 'Yellow': -2, 'blue': -5, 'red': 4}

tweet0 = "Hello, I am groot"
tweet1 = "My name is red"
tweets = [tweet0, tweet1]

words = [tweet.split(" ") for tweet in tweets]

Results = list()

for i in range(len(tweets)):
    # words[i] are the words from the tweet i
    value = 0
    for word in words[i]:
        if word in dict:
            value += dict[word]
    Results.append(value)

print (Results)
```

The output with this example is:

```
[-2, 4]
```

-2 because only "I" is present in tweet0, and 4 because "red" is present in tweet1.

As you notice, since there is a "," after "Hello", it doesn't take this word into account. This can be fix with an other in statement, and we can also add .lower() method to the str to avoid any problem with the capital letters.

Since I'm not sure about what you want, I just did this proof of concept. I could improve it if you would give us clear examples.

Comment: That is absolutelly what I was looking for, and I was able to do it correctly.
I'm new to this, and the trick with "len" was unknown to me.
Sincerely, thank you very much!